# PHP - array_combine()

Tags: php

I have been trying to use php to make a elementary video viewer out of my server, but it generally failed due to the fact that I was totally a newbie in php. I've been keep getting this error -     E_WARNING Error in file *** at line **: array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given E_WARNING Error in file *** at line **(same line): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

And nothing is displayed as result.

What can I do?

BTW, here's the source code

```
    $dir = $_GET["path"];
    $files = scandir($dir);
    $thelists=NULL;

    foreach (array_combine($files, $thelists) as $file => $thelist) {
            if ($file != "." || $file != ".." || pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_E$
                    $thelist .= '<a href=browse.php?path=.$_GET["path"].'.$$
            }
            else if ($file == "..") {
                    $thelist .= '<a href="javascript:history.back(1);">Back$
            }
            else {
                    echo "<a href=http://twentyone.ml/cloud/video.php?file=$
            }
    }
?>
<body>
<h1>Directory listing for <?php echo $dir; ?></h1>
<p><?php print_r($thelists); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed $thelists by the following code :

(Part of it... just a bit of foreach())

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
        //$file_info = new finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mime_type = mime_content_type($dir.'/'.$file);//$file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($dir.'/'.$file));
        if ($file != "." || $file != ".." || strpos($mime_type,'video') !== false) {
            echo '<a href=browse.php?path='.$_GET["path"].'/'.$file.'>'.$file.'</a><br />';
        }
```

Yay!

Answer (score 1):

First of all i can't understand why are you combine `Null` in array ?

`$thelists` is null in array combine you need to add array instead of null

Change `$thelists=NULL;` to `$thelists=array();`

Comment: Sorry, but I already tried that... Didn't work so I tried null and even THAT didn't work.

Comment: Error : array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Comment: Try with array_merge @iCore

Comment: That sort of works, but I don't get the file listing... But thanks for your help:) @ Maninderpreet Singh

Comment: Happy to help @iCore if it is help then accept it have a look http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work